# How to optimize finding relatives of $(this)

Tags: jquery

I often find myself trying to do something related to the element clicked, and end up with a string that looks something like this:

```
$('input.Button').click(function(event) {
   $(this).parent('div.Picture').parent('div.SelectOption').children('div.Options').children('p.Option').show();
});
```

I strongly suspect traveling up the DOM via parent and back down via children is costly, not to mention a PITA to write, but I don't know a better way to do it yet. If someone could tell me how to write something like this better, I would appreciate it. In all cases, the element that is changing is related to the element clicked, so I can't just do a simple:

```
$('input.Button').click(function(event) {
   $('p.Option').show();
});
```

Because that would show everything, rather than just the one in the same container as the input button.

Note, this was a generic example, but I'm finding my work filled with examples like this and I don't know how to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) for this.

```
$('input.Button').click(function(event) {
   $(this).closest('div.SelectOption').find('div.Options > p.Option').show();
});
```